# How to change the compile flags based on the build type while keeping the build recipe same in Makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a recipe to build the targets in my Makefile. What I want to do is change the compiler flags based on whether the user selects the `debug` build or the `release` build. To do this, I tried using a target-specific variable called `FLAGS` which gets assigned appropriately when the user builds the `debug` or the `release` target. However, the main target recipe is not able to view the values of the `FLAGS` variable.

My Makefile looks like:

```
CXX = g++ 
CXX_FLAGS = -pedantic -Wall -Wextra                                                                                                                            
TARGET_FLAGS = $(CXX_FLAGS) -shared -fPIC

OPT_FLAGS = -Ofast -march=native
DBG_FLAGS = -g3 -Og -ggdb

SRC = $(wildcard ./src/*/impl.cpp)
INCLPATH = ./headers
OBJECTS = $(patsubst ./src/%/impl.cpp,./build/%.o,$(SRC))
TARGET = lfds.so

.PHONY: release
release: FLAGS = $(OPT_FLAGS) $(TARGET)

.PHONY: debug
debug: FLAGS = $(DBG_FLAGS) $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
        echo "Hi $(FLAGS)"
        $(CXX) -I$(INCLPATH) $(TARGET_FLAGS) $(FLAGS) $^ -o $@
./build/%.o: ./src/%/impl.cpp
        echo "Hi $(FLAGS)"
        $(CXX) -I$(INCLPATH) $(CXX_FLAGS) $(FLAGS) -c $< -o $@

.PHONY: clean
clean:
        rm -rf $(OBJECTS)
        rm $(TARGET)
```

When I run `make debug` and `make release`, the `echo` commands prints `Hi` , which tells me that the variable `FLAGS` was never assigned. Does anyone know why this is happening? Note that I don't want to build two different `targets` one for `debug` and one for `release`, rather I want a single target which get built with different flags based on what the user wants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a syntax mistake my Makefile. As per the [syntax](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Target_002dspecific.html), the target-specific variables should be set in a different line and the dependencies should be specified in a different line. The updated Makefile works correctly. Here is the updated version:

```
CXX = g++                                                                                                                                                      
CXX_FLAGS = -pedantic -Wall -Wextra
TARGET_FLAGS = $(CXX_FLAGS) -shared -fPIC

OPT_FLAGS = -Ofast -march=native
DBG_FLAGS = -g3 -Og -ggdb

SRC = $(wildcard ./src/*/impl.cpp)
INCLPATH = ./headers
OBJECTS = $(patsubst ./src/%/impl.cpp,./build/%.o,$(SRC))
TARGET = lfds.so

.PHONY: release
release: FLAGS = $(OPT_FLAGS)
release: $(TARGET)

.PHONY: debug
debug: FLAGS=$(DBG_FLAGS)
debug: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
        @echo "Hi $(FLAGS)"
        $(CXX) -I$(INCLPATH) $(TARGET_FLAGS) $(FLAGS) $^ -o $@
./build/%.o: ./src/%/impl.cpp
        @echo "Hi $(FLAGS)"
        $(CXX) -I$(INCLPATH) $(CXX_FLAGS) $(FLAGS) -c $< -o $@

.PHONY: clean
clean:
        rm -rf $(OBJECTS)
        rm $(TARGET)
```